# how to create login screen webservices in C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new on .net,my requirement is how i can make an login screen websercies in C# ?which have 2 paramaeteres like username and password,any one please give me a right direction to make an webservices in C#,thanks in advance.

**Updated**

```
 public string Login(string userName, string password)
{
    string retDesc = "";
    ws.CsmLoginInDto obj = new ws.CsmLoginInDto();

    return retDesc;

}
```

Comment: [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/creating-web-service-for-login-page/)

Comment: @jbutler483 thanks for ur reply bro,let me check..

Answer (score 0):

See this link.
It is very easy. You just create two text box . And you write code in C# file to connect with database. It will check value in database. And return if it is correct or not.
[link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/how-to-create-simple-login-form-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a web service that your application can consume. That service will communicate with the database and also with the application. So when a user requests to log in using his credentials your request will be sent to the web service. The web service will check the user credentials with the database and decide if you are a valid user or not.

So what's happening is that your web service is between your application and your database. And you are communicating to your database through consuming the web service.

***Resources :***

[***Consuming WCF Services***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226529.aspx)

Here's a scenario that might help you.

**WCF Web Service :**

*User.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LogInService
{
    [DataContract]
    class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*IUser.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LogInService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IUser
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool ValidateUser(User user);
    }
}
```

*LogInClass.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LogInService
{
    class LogInClass : IUser
    {
        public bool ValidateUser(User user) 
        {
            // connection to the database and checking user validity code goes here.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

***Note :**You might need to make some changes to your configuration file accordingly*

Now to consume this service in your client you must have a client that contains a reference of this service. To do that i've created a simple Console client application. And added the reference of our currently developed service.

Then using the ReferenceClient of our developed service i've invoked the ValidateUser() method.

**Client :**

*Program.cs*

```
using Client.LogInServiceReferenceForClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LogInServiceReferenceForClient.UserClient client = new LogInServiceReferenceForClient.UserClient();
            User aUser = new User();
            aUser.UserName = Console.ReadLine();
            aUser.Password = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(client.ValidateUser(aUser).ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. You just need to write code inside ValidateUser() function that will check the user from making query in database.

Comment: yes i have wcf service,in which a huge amount of data is,and also everything is defined in it,my senior told me that first you consume that WCF service in C#,then make an services for login and registration page,now i have consume the Wcf service as a reference and it is working fine,now i am stuck on this point that what i can do ahead,kindly guid me bro..

Comment: If you have consumed the service then now you are free to use that service. Suppose if your web service have a method that takes 2 parameters which is username and password and returns a bool checking the username and password from database which indicates the user is valid or not then from your application call that service method and get the returned bool to identify the user validity.

Comment: bro kindely see my updated question,i have paste my function,i have make the object of the login class,in which username and password available,now kindly can u guid me further that how i can access these strings(uname,pass) ?